# Revenue Measure in Datawarehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

I am building a Data warehouse for finance team and we have measure

revenue,
expense ,
revenue - expense = gross margin

They are connect to following dimension

Project,
Org,
Client,
Date

However some of the Project id which are present in Revenue are not present in the expense and vice-versa.

Should I keep them in separate fact table to get all the data ?

If I keep them separate how will I get gross margin?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your Question is : 
you are calculating the Revenue and Expense based on project_id.

Assumption : There are projects which will have no Revenue, few might have no Expense too.
In that case, those project_id will have 0 as Revenue or Expense. Ideally, that's how you will get the Gross. If you use separate tables, then there is no point of Gross calculation.